# Tire - query with conditional/custom _score

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am searching with tire normally with filters, all fine.
But I want to be precise in search, for a sample if i search for "dfssdljf" it wont return me any data, but currently it return me completely irrelevant data.

According to Tire attributes, i can reject result with _score <0.5 but its only during iteration after search. But after i tried this - its a bad idea because i have pagination which can be messed during iteration.

Point is, if i can do something line "WHERE _score > 0.5" during Tire search ?

Comment: How do you know, that 0.5 score is low or high enough?

Comment: @alex i've seen that all request below it are completely irrelevant

Comment: you should investigate, why they are irrelevant, why if you query for `dfssdljf`, you return wrong data, possible it's because of custom analyzers, etc.

Comment: i do have our custom analyzer with "tokenizer" => 'standart' and "filters" => ["standart","asciifolding", "lowercase"], but seems they should not mess search this way, thanks in advance Alex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html from `min_score` and in tire search you could use

```
Tire::Search::Search.new index_name do
  query your_query
  min_score 0.5
end
```